# Change location at which CollapsingToolbar transitions to from image to background color (Android Development)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-tablayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to tweak the behavior of the CollapsingToolbarLayout element in my Android app.

Using the solution linked below, I have created a collapsing toolbar containing a TabLayout and a background image which disappears when the user scrolls up. Everything works as expected, but I'm wondering if I can change the position at which the CollapsingToolbar transitions from the image to the background color.

When using tabs, the transition from the image to the solid background color happens almost instantaneously when scrolling up. Without tabs, the toolbar transition doesn't occur until the toolbar is almost completely collapsed. I'm wondering if there's a way to delay the transition when using tabs so that it doesn't occur as quickly when scrolling.

Below is the XML code for my toolbar and tab layouts as well as screenshots of current and desired behavior.

[Image: Current transition behavior (with tabs)](http://s25.postimg.cc/y9kv9bonj/ezgif_3464099692.gif)

[Image: Desired transition behavior (only achieved without using tabs)](http://s25.postimg.cc/n8pq4awen/ezgif_2815138730.gif)

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="235dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_scrim"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/scrim"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="104dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleMarginTop="13dp"
            >

            <!-- app title -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/app_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingBottom="2.5dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Collapsing toolbar with tabs solution: blog.grafixartist.com/parallax-scrolling-tabs-design-support-library/

Answer (score 0):

Add `app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"` to your `ImageView`

Comment: This doesn't work. :/ The parallax multiplier only affects the rate at which the image collapses, but it doesn't actually change the point at which the toolbar transitions from background image to solid color.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the `visibleScrimHeightTrigger()`  to fit your needs.
[scrimVisibleHeightTrigger()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html#attr_android.support.design:scrimVisibleHeightTrigger)